# JASPER REPORT- How to modify subDataSetQuery from java program

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am using the *iReport* GUI designer which has generated the jrxml containing columns and queries.

I am using a table in report, so basically jrxml created from the tool contain below two query:

```
<subDataset name="Report_DataSet" uuid="944f793f-df0c-4b1a-b408-57ef71ef73a0">
<queryString language="SQL">
<![CDATA[select BILL_ACCOUNT, SUBSCRIBER_NAME,  BILL_FROM_DATE_MDY, BILL_TO_DATE_MDY, PREVIOUS_BALANCE, CURRENT_CHARGES, AMT_DUE FROM INVOICE_DETAIL WHERE ROWNUM <= 100]]>
</queryString>
<field name="BILL_ACCOUNT" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="SUBSCRIBER_NAME" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="BILL_FROM_DATE_MDY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="BILL_TO_DATE_MDY" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="PREVIOUS_BALANCE" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="CURRENT_CHARGES" class="java.lang.String"/>
<field name="AMT_DUE" class="java.lang.String"/>
</subDataset>

<queryString>
<![CDATA[select BILL_ACCOUNT FROM INVOICE_DETAIL WHERE ROWNUM <= 1]]>
</queryString>
```

So, I want to modify **"queryString"** in my java program so that I can change query dynamically like can apply filters and where condition etc...so I tried below approach in my java program.

```
final String model = "/JRXML/report1.jrxml";
String queryString = "select BILL_ACCOUNT, SUBSCRIBER_NAME,  BILL_FROM_DATE_MDY, BILL_TO_DATE_MDY, PREVIOUS_BALANCE, CURRENT_CHARGES, AMT_DUE FROM INVOICE_DETAIL WHERE ROWNUM <= 10";

    Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
    JRResultSetDataSource jasperReports = new JRResultSetDataSource(rset);
    JasperDesign design = JRXmlLoader.load(model);
    JRDesignQuery subQuery = new JRDesignQuery()
    subQuery.setText(queryString);
    Map<String, JRDataset> datasetMap = design.getDatasetMap();
    JRDesignDataset subDataset = (JRDesignDataset)            datasetMap.get("Report_DataSet");
    subDataset.setQuery(subQuery);
    JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, jasperReports);
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "/JRXML/MyReport_cherry.pdf");
```

For now the query has a simple difference in fetching of **ROWNUM**.

The report that is getting generated is blank... without any error and **warning** of: "WARNING: The supplied java.sql.Connection object is null.
Aug 20, 2015 9:07:15 PM net.sf.jasperreports.engine.query.JRJdbcQueryExecuter "

But if I remove the query from *Java* program, my report is perfectly generated. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here??

**Question :** I want to modify the query in *Java* program that is created by subDataset (It is created by using table in iReport )

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can achieve this by passing a parameter like
select * from Table where field = $P!{yourPar}
where ROWNUM value can be passed from your java program. Hope it helps.